# Compare the growth rate of given functions.

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

In this problem we have to compare the growth rate of the following functions.
$$n^{log n}$$
$$(log n)^{n}$$

I have tried to solve this question but got stuck at a point.

My solution:

Let$$n=2^m$$
$$\therefore n^{log n}=(2^m)^{log_2 2^m}$$
$$=2^{m^{m}}$$
AND
$$(log n)^{n} = (log_2 2^m)^{2^m}$$
$$m^{2^{m}}$$

I am not able to compare between:
$$=2^{m^{m}}$$
AND
$$m^{2^{m}}$$

Please help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: Can you compare between $2^m$ and $m^2$?

Comment: Yes. 2^m will grow faster than m^2 as it is an exponential function and m^2 is a polynomial function.

Comment: $n ^{\log n} $ should be $2^{m \log_2 m}$ and $(\log n)^n$ should be $m^{(2^m)}$

Comment: So... your goal is to compare $$2^{m^2}\qquad\text{vs.}\qquad 2^{2m\log_2m}$$ Can you at least compare $m^2$ and $2m\log_2m$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parenthesize your towers.  $n^{\log n}=(2^m)^m,$ not $2^{(m^m)}$ which is the correct way to read the stack without parentheses.  We are therefore comparing 
$$(2^m)^m \text { and } m^{(2^m)}$$
Now $(2^m)^m=2^{(m^2)}$.  For large $m$ we have 
$$m \gt 2\\2^m \gt m^2\\m^{(2^m)} \gt (2^m)^m$$